# Get record real value after overriding it

Tags: laravel, model

I've overridden a a record value like the following :

```
public function getWeightAttribute($weight)
 {
        if($weight)
        {
          return $weight;
        }

        return 70;
}
```

Now I have a collection of that model and I want to know if the original value was null or not.
I want to do it without connecting to DB again, Actually I want to make sure the user has filled the weight and some other fields while registering.
Some sections are working based on the above override and I don't want to mess them up neither use extra connections to db.
Thanks In Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the original value, you can use:-

```
$fetchData->getAttributes()['weight'];
```

Comment: Wow, It's your lucky day. It worked like a charm, By the way welcome to the site and please put your codes inside code block.